# Macro to allocate a static array in compile time

Tags: c, oop

Is there a way to allocate a static array in compile time ?

Example:

```
    typedef struct Node
    {
        struct Node* prev;
        struct Node* next;                 
        bool allocated;     
        void* object;
    }node_t;

    #define ALLOC( size ) { node_t vec[size]; return &vec[0] }     

    #define list_const_func_pointers(max_list_size)  \
    {                                                \
        .maximum_list_size = max_list_size,          \
        .vectorLL = ALLOC( max_list_size ),          \
        .init = init_linked_list,                    \
        .my_st_malloc = my_static_malloc             \
    }
   
    struct static_doublyll_t
    {
        node_t* head;
        node_t* last;
        int32_t list_size;  // "actual list size"
        const uint32_t maximum_list_size;  // Tamanho do array de node_t alocado estaticamente.    
        node_t* vectorLL;  // Aponta para uma array de node_t alocado estaticamente.
        
        void (*const init)(static_doublyll_t*);
            
        node_t* (*const my_st_malloc)(static_doublyll_t* l);
        
        static_doublyll_t* this_pointer;  // unnecessary because "recursion problem".   
    };

// Driver code:

    #define list_size 20
    
    static static_doublyll_t list = list_const_func_pointers(list_size); // init the const "variables".
```

Notes:

- I need that the compiler return unique memory blocks (statically allocated at compile time) on each macro call.
- This macro in the above example is what I need to work:

  ```
    #define ALLOC( size ) { node_t vec[size]; return &vec[0] }"
  ```

Comment: "allocate"? Is that important?

Comment: To ensure your question isn't garbled on display, please format code samples using triple-backtick fences (or ensure all code is indented 4 spaces). See [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: The macro `#define ALLOC(size) { node_t vec[size]; return &vec[0] }` defines a code block (more or less) but the allocated vector goes out of scope immediately.  It isn't going to work well.  You'd need a semicolon before the `}` too, but that isn't going to fix things.  You might be able to add `static` before `node_t` and then get something to work — but it feels to me like you're going in an obscure direction for no obvious benefit.

Comment: I made something vaguely related as a goof that you might be able to use https://www.onlinegdb.com/SkQQxq9sL

Comment: @PaulDempsey Dempsy, i used the stackoverflow code insertion on edit mode, but the caracter automatically inserted were ` insert your code here `. After i tried to edit my question, but i didn't find any button to edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something more simple.

```
    typedef struct Node
    {
        struct Node* prev;
        struct Node* next;                 
        bool allocated;     
        void* object;
    }node_t;


    #define DECLARE(name, max_list_size)            \
    static node_t node_t##name[max_list_size];     \
    struct static_doublyll_t name =                 \
    {                                               \
        .maximum_list_size = max_list_size,         \
        .vectorLL = node_t##name,                  \
    }
   
    struct static_doublyll_t
    {
        node_t* head;
        node_t* last;
        int32_t list_size;  // "actual list size"
        const uint32_t maximum_list_size;  // Tamanho do array de node_t alocado estaticamente.    
        node_t* vectorLL;  // Aponta para uma array de node_t alocado estaticamente.
    };

// Driver code:

    #define list_size 20
    
    DECLARE(list, list_size);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need that the compiler return unique memory blocks(statically allocated at compile time) on each macro call.

Macros are not "called" in the same sense as functions, and they do not "return" anything.  The compiler *expands* macro invocations at compile time, and compiles the result as C code, in the context of the surrounding C code.

You are using the macro in a context where it needs to expand to an expression of array or pointer type.  Your best bet for that would be to use a compound literal:

```
#define ALLOC(size) ( (node_t []) { [size - 1] = {0} } )
```

That will produce an array with static storage duration only at file scope (that is, outside any function).  It's unclear from the example code whether that would serve your purpose.  I observe, however, that the only other context where what you describe could make sense would be in the initializer of a local object with static storage duration, and if that's what you have then you could consider just moving that out of its function.

Note well that what you describe does not make any sense at all for something that needs to provide a separate array on each call to some function, nor where the `size` parameter is not a compile-time constant at each invocation.  Those kinds of things generally demand dynamic allocation.

Comment: i only want to initialize a list at compile time. If i want to use more than a single list in some project, i can use the same library. Example: intitialize two lists(static global variables) 
static static_doublyll_t list = list_const_func_pointers(20);
static static_doublyll_t list_1 = list_const_func_pointers(10);

Comment: from what i tested here, it solved "#define ALLOC(size) ( (node_t []) { [size] = {0} } )", i just removed the -1. Could you confirm to me if this macro produces the same effect as "static node_t vec[size];" ???

Comment: i would like to solve the "this pointer" problem if possible too, but i dont think that have some solution in pure c language. Example: ~~~list.init(&list);    list_1.init(&list_1); void init_linked_list(static_doublyll_t* l)
{
 l->head = NULL;
 l->last = NULL; 
 l->list_size = -1;  // Lista vazia.
    
 int i; 
 for (i = 0 ; i < l->maximum_list_size ; i++)
 {
  l->vectorLL[i].allocated = false;
  l->vectorLL[i].next = NULL;
  l->vectorLL[i].prev = NULL;
  l->vectorLL[i].object = NULL;
 }
}
~~~

Comment: @baldhead, the macro I presented expands to a compound literal whose characteristics depend, as I already describe, on where it is used.  When used (validly) outside any function, the array it represents has `size` elements of type `node_t`, and the array has static storage duration.  Note that the `size - 1` in that macro is the *index* of the last element.  Arrays are indexed from 0, so if you remove the `- 1` then the array must have `size + 1` elements to accommodate index `size`.

Comment: @baldhead, I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "the 'this pointer' problem", but that sounds like a separate question.

Comment: if i need 20 elements in an array, i need to pass 20( 0 to 19 = 20 elements ), and not size - 1( 20 - 1 = 19 elements).

Comment: "this pointer problem" is another question yes(but is related with the same library that iam writing), thank`s.

Comment: @baldhead, regarding the -1, again, the macro given in this answer yields an array with the number of elements specified by the macro argument.  That is, 20 elements when the macro argument is 20.  The one in your second comment gives an array with 21 elements when the macro argument is 20.